# PyCharm Community Edition won't display in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, pycharm, window-placement

I installed PyCharm Community Edition via Ubuntu Software Center, and when I try to open the application it indicates that PyCharm is open and I can see the window when I hover over the icon, but it won't display on the desktop in full view. I have already tried to uninstall and reinstall this, and the issue continues to persist.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by “it won't display on the desktop in full view?” A screenshot of the situation may help your readers to understand it better. Thanks.

Comment: Hi David Foerster! Thank you for the advice here.  After working on this for a couple more hours I found that there was an issue with the display functionality on my Ubuntu where it thought that I had 2 displays.  Therefore, it was showing the PyCharm on the other "display".  Once I changed the display settings PyCharm showed up on my display.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the display functionality on my Ubuntu where it thought that I had 2 displays. Therefore it was showing PyCharm on the other "display". Once I changed the display settings, PyCharm showed up on my display.

Answer (score -2):

This happened to me a while back and i tried resetting and it worked, my recommendation, restart Ubuntu, run it, if that doesnt work; uninstall PyCharm then restart Ubuntu, then re-install, just restarting always worked for me.

Comment: This is also an option. But not the best answer.